# How to find the maximum value of a given range, dependent on the value in a separate column

Tags: excel

[Screenshot of the Excel worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMF3o.png) 
I'm working with historic stock prices, and using eight columns I have:

- Column A: High
- Column B: Low
- Column C: Close
- Column D: C<sub>x</sub>-C<sub>x-4</sub>
- Column E: Counts the number of consecutive positive numbers in column D
- Column F: Counts the number of consecutive negative numbers in column D
- Column G: Calculate the difference between the maximum of column A and minimum of column B *within* a given sequence.

As an example G1 should equal:

```
=max(A1:A5)-min(B1:B5)
```

G6 should equal:

```
=max(A6:A8)-min(B6:B8)
```

G9 should equal:

```
=max(A9:A11)-min(B9:B11)
```

And so on.

I'd like to know if it is possible to automate this calculation, possibly with the use of one or more additional columns.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

This may not be the most efficient solution as you need to add two helper columns, but if I understand your requirements correctly, then this idea should work well enough.

First, let's assume that there are 100 rows in your data set.  Given that, enter the formula "=A100" in cell G100 and the formula "=B100" in cell H100.  This sets up the boundary condition for the formulas in columns G and H.  Now, in cell G99, enter this formula:

```
"=IF(E99="",G100,IF(E100="",A99,MAX(A99,G100)))"
```

What this formula does is set up a "running maximum" with the following logic:

- If the cell in E99 is blank, copy the running maximum from G100, else:
- If the cell in E99 is not blank but the cell in E100 is, set up a new running maximum from the cell in A99, else:
- Take the maximum of A99 and G100 as the new running maximum.

Similarly, copy the following formula into cell H100:

```
"=IF(F99="",H100,IF(F100="",B99,MIN(B99,H100)))"
```

This follows the same logic as the previous formula, but takes the minimum of column B.

Copy or autofill these formulas to the top of the data set.  This should now give you running maximum for column A and a running minimum for column B.

The next step is to calculate the difference.  I notice from your question, that you only seem to be interested in calculating this difference at the top of each range (G1, G6, G9, etc.), rather than doing it in every row.  Given that, we need a slightly more complicated formula.

The boundary condition for this formula is simply "=G1-H1" entered in cell I1.  In cell I2, enter this:

```
"=IF(OR(AND(E2<>"",E1=""),AND(F2<>"",F1="")),G2-H2,"")"
```

How this works is that it check two conditions that indicate a range boundary:

- E1 is blank and E2 is not

  or
- F1 is blank and F2 is not

If either of these conditions hold, the IF statement is true and "G2-H2" is diplayed, otherwise a blank cell is displayed.  Now copy or autofill this formula to the bottom of the data set.

As a final step, you can now hide columns G and H if you don't need them displayed.  This should now give you the results I think you're looking for.  Please let me know if this doesn't work out for you.